# What's the correct .csv format to make a pie chart in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I have external data that I'd like to make into a pie chart with Highchart.  I want to dump the data into a .csv file, but what is the format?

This documentation only shows how to format .csv files for bar graphs: http://highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use#preprocessing

What if I want to make a pie chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on Highcharts' forum:

http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=8614&hilit=pie+chart+.csv

Make sure you don't have an extra new line at the end of your .csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no correct csv format for highcharts. Highcharts only accepts data in one of [these three formats](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series--data). The goal of the data-preprocessing is to transform the data into a supported javascript array format.

Quoting the reference:

**data** : Array
An array of data points for the series. The points can be given in three ways:

1. A list of numerical values. In this case, the numberical values will be interpreted and y values, and x values will be automatically calculated, either starting at 0 and incrementing by 1, or from pointStart and pointInterval given in the plotOptions. If the axis is has categories, these will be used. Example:

   ```
   data: [0, 5, 3, 5]
   ```
2. A list of arrays with two values. In this case, the first value is the x value and the second is the y value. If the first value is a string, it is applied as the name of the point, and the x value is incremented following the above rules. Example:

   ```
   data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]
   ```
3. A list of object with named values. In this case the objects are point configuration objects as seen under options.point. Example:

   ```
   data: [{
       name: 'Point 1',
       color: '#00FF00',
       y: 0
   }, {
       name: 'Point 2',
       color: '#FF00FF',
       y: 5
   }]
   ```

Defaults to "".